# Find the singularities and residues that correspond. Show details

Tags: residue-calculus

> Find all the singularities in the finite plane and the corresponding residues. Show the details.

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{1-e^z}$$

So I'm trying to find the singularities. So the singularities are located when the denominator = 0 and that occurs when $e^z = 1$ which occurs when $z = 2 \pi in$ when $n \in \mathbb{R}$

Now what? How can I find the residues?

so the residue formula that I know is:

$$\operatorname{Res}_{z = z_0}f(z) = \lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0) f(z)$$

That's what I'm trying to use. But how do I determine this when $z_0$ isn't fixed?

Answer (score 1):

For each $n\in\Bbb Z$, you have\begin{align}\operatorname{res}_{z=2\pi in}\frac1{1-e^z}&=\lim_{z\to2\pi in}\frac{z-2\pi in}{1-e^z}\\&=-\frac1{\lim_{z\to2\pi in}\frac{e^z-e^{2\pi in}}{z-2\pi in}}\\&=-\frac1{\exp'(2\pi in)}\\&=-\frac1{e^{2\pi in}}\\&=-1.\end{align}

Comment: How did you get from the 1st to the 2nd line?

Comment: $$\lim_{z\to a}f(z)=\frac1{\lim_{z\to a}\frac1{f(z)}}$$

Comment: where did the $e^z - e^{2 \pi n}$ come from?

Comment: Anyway you can show me using thes residue formula above? I don't know how you got from 2nd to third or 1st to 2nd

Comment: There is no $e^z-e^{2\pi n}$ in my answer.

Comment: sorry in line 2, there's a $e^z - e^{2 \pi i n}$, where did that come from

Comment: From the fact that $e^{2\pi in}=1$. Therefore$$\frac{e^z-1}{z-2\pi in}=\frac{e^z-e^{2\pi in}}{z-2\pi in}.$$

Comment: ohhhh. If you're interested I also found this: https://www.slader.com/discussion/question/find-all-the-singularities-in-the-finite-plane-and-the-6/